# Superimposing normal distribution in ggplot2: Bug?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to superimpose two normal distributions. However, if I restrict xlim to a narrow intervall, the plot looks quite weird:

[image: see here]

```
library(ggplot2)
x=seq(1,6,.01)
dat <- data.frame(
  c1 = dnorm(x,4.95, .72),
  c2 = dnorm(x,4.85, .91), x = x
)
  ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=x)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(y=dat[,1]), fill="red", alpha=0.6) +
  geom_polygon(aes(y=dat[,2]), fill="blue", alpha=0.6) +
  xlab("Scale") + ylab("") + xlim(1,6)
```

If the range is increased, it works:

[image: see here]

```
 x=seq(1,10,.01)
    dat <- data.frame(
      c1 = dnorm(x,4.95, .72),
      c2 = dnorm(x,4.85, .91), x = x
    )
      ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=x)) + 
      geom_polygon(aes(y=dat[,1]), fill="red", alpha=0.6) +
      geom_polygon(aes(y=dat[,2]), fill="blue", alpha=0.6) +
      xlab("Scale") + ylab("") + xlim(1,10)
```

(See Figures for the output). However, I want the x-axis restricted to 1 to 6. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Also, do you have any suggestions how to add labels on the right side of the plot?

Comment: By the way, this has nothing to do with the superimposition. Plotting a single polygon only would yield a similar result.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `geom_area` with `position = "identity"`. Rearranging and cleaning a bit,

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(dat %>% gather(var, val, -x), aes(x = x, y = val, fill = var)) + 
    geom_area(alpha = 0.6, position = 'identity') + 
    labs(x = "Scale", y = NULL, fill = 'Variable')
```

[image: area plot]

Comment: `geom_area` is neat.

Answer (score 2):

It’s not a bug — you’re cutting off the range before y rejoins the x-axis, so that’s where the polygon wraps around to its first point. You can use `geom_ribbon` if you want to base a polygon on the x-axis.

```
ggplot(dat) +
    aes(x, ymin = 0) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymax  = c1), fill = 'red', alpha = 0.6) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymax = c2), fill = 'blue', alpha = 0.6) +
    xlim(1, 6)
```

Comment: Thanks. How do you add a legend with "c1 - red" and "c2 - blue" to this?

Comment: @Paul It doesn’t work with approach. The other answer, by alistaire, shows how to do it: you need to reshape your data so that it contains a variable describing the distribution (`var` in his example).